# How to show the list of rules to activate and inactivate them?

Tags: c#, sonarqube

We are using Sonarqube Version 6.5 (build 27846) - LGPL v3 for C# language, I have created a new quality profile, but when I click the "Activate More" button; Does not show the list of rules to activate and inactivate them, shows message "NO CODING RULES".
Nor does it work with the sonarway profile, does not show the list of rules to inactivate those that do not apply to our business niche.
I have not yet run the first analysis in this version because we have only 110 active rules, for this reason I want to deactivate the rest before running the analysis.

Language: c#
Plugin: 6.3 (build 2862) installed
[NO CODING RULES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WliAS.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with SonarQube 6.5, built-in profiles are not editable.

Regarding your custom profile, this is likely caused by a corrupt ElasticSearch index.

- stop your server
- delete `$SONARQUBE_HOME/data/es`
- restart the server (the time this takes will vary by instance size)

Comment: Thanks, I followed the steps that you informed and I could already see the rules and inactivate them for my quality profile.